# In Perl, how can I parse a date string and subtract days from the date it represents?

Tags: perl, datetime

I have a date in string as in `$str1="20120704"`. I want to subtract 1 day from that date, and store the value of date as a string in `$str2`. How can i do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is very similar to another question you asked a couple of days ago. So, unsurprisingly, the solution is also very similar.

Time::Piece and Time::Seconds have been part of the standard Perl distribution since version 5.10.0. You should use them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds;

my $format = '%Y%m%d';
my $str1 = '20120704';

my $dt1 = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, $format);
my $dt2 = $dt1 - ONE_DAY;
my $str2 = $dt2->strftime($format);
say $str2;
```

Comment: Using perl 5.8. Will try to download the time piece module and try it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot.   It's working.   Final output date i am stored in the below way. $outDate=sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", $year2, $month2, $day2); Hope it's correct.

Comment: You seem to be using variables that don't come from my example. So it's hard to know if your code is correct. In general using a `strftime` method would be preferred over manually building a string using `sprintf`.

Answer (score 9):

Perl stores dates and times in an internal format that can easily be manipulated. What you have is a date in YYYYMMDD format. So, what you need to do is:

1. Convert your date (which is in YYYYMMDD format)  into Perl's date/time storage format.
2. Use Perl to manipulate this date and time.
3. When you want to output the results, you have to convert it back into the format you want.

#### Convert your date (which is in YYYYMMDD format)  into Perl's date/time storage format.

The best module for doing this is [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) which comes with Perl. It's pretty simple:

```
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, '%Y%m%d');
```

`$date` will now be your date and time, but stored in a format Perl can understand and manipulate. The `%Y%m%d` is a description of your format, so Perl knows where to find the year, month, and day of the month. You can look at [strftime](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/) to see the various format parameters. In your case:

- `%Y` - represents the year with the century, such as `2012`.
- `%m` - Represents the month as a two digit number such as `03` or `12`.
- `%d` - Represents the date of the month as a two digit number from `01` to `31` if there are that many days in the month.

#### Next: Manipulate your date.

You can use another module called [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) that will take care of this for you.

`Time::Seconds` defines a bunch of constants like `ONE_DAY` which makes thing easier:

```
 my $date = $date - ONE_DAY;
```

#### Finally: Convert the date back to the format you want.

Again, `Time::Piece` has a nifty, easy way to do this for you:

```
$date->ymd("");
```

This converts `$date` into a string in the Year-month-day format. By default, this will put a `-` between each part. However, you can pass it the character you want to use as the divider. In this case, nothing.

All together:

```
use Time::Piece   # For manipulating and storing the date
use Time::Seconds # For the nice constants such as ONE_DAY and ONE_WEEK

my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($str1, '%Y%m%d');
my $date = $date - ONE_DAY;
my $str2 = $date->ymd('');
```

That's pretty simple.

---

[Dave Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11384156/368630) gave you an excellent answer. I'd normally just up vote him, and leave it at that. However, he also mentioned you asked a similar question a few days ago. To me, it means that you might have used Dave Cross' previous answer, but you didn't understand it. That's not good.

Look at the documentation of [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) and [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html). Take a look at [strfdate](http://www.unix.com/man-page/FreeBSD/3/strftime/) and play around with that. Learn it and understand it. If you have any questions about these, ask them on Stackoverflow. People on Stackoverflow are happier answering questions like "How does this work?" rather than "Can you do this for me?". They'll take the time and effort to explain the first while most will either ignore the latter or give you a cursory answer.

This will make you a better programmer which means you're more valuable with your company and that translate into higher pay. It is worth your time and effort.

Try to understand it. Play around with it.

---

#### Addendum

> Was using a older perl version 5.8 and thought of using the existing modules in the system. Also not sure of how time::piece works

That's a pretty old version of Perl, but it's common on Solaris.

In this case, we'll do it the very old fashion way.

There are two Perl function called [localtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) and [gmtime](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/gmtime.html). These take the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 and convert it into an array of values with each value representing a particular part of the time (month, year, day, hours, minutes, etc.).

What you need are inverse functions -- something that can take an array of values and convert it into the number of seconds since 1970. Since Perl 3.0, there has been such a module that's included in each version of Perl. In Perl 5.x, tt's called [Time::Local](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Local.html). It gives you two functions called `timelocal` and `timegm`. These are the inverse functions we need.

First, we need to split up your string into separate year, month, and day, put that into an array for either `timegm` or `timelocal` to turn into the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.

Next, we'll subtract the number of seconds in a day. This is 60 * 60 * 24 or 86,400.

Finally, we'll convert that new *date* into an array that you can use to display the date in YYYYMMDD order.

Two important caveats!

- The function assumes that the month is from 0 to 11 and not 1 to 12. This allows you to create an array to convert from month number to name. This means we have to subtract 1 from the month before we give it to `gmtime` and add one when take it back from `timegm`.
- The year is the number of years since 1900. That means we have to subtract 1900 before we give it to `gmtime`, and add 1900 when we take it back from `timegm`.

And, now the program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Local;

my $date = 20120615;    #2012-June-15

$date =~ /(....)(..)(..)/;  #Parse the date

my $year = $1;
my $month = $2;
my $day = $3;

$month -= 1;    #Month is 0 to 11 and not 1 to 12
$year -= 1900;  #Year is number of years since 1900

my $seconds = 0;
my $minutes = 0;
my $hours = 0;

my $perl_date = timegm($seconds, $minutes, $hours, $day, $month, $year);

my $perl_date2 = $perl_date - (60 * 60 *24);

my ($seconds2, $minutes2, $hours2, $day2, $month2, $year2)  = gmtime($perl_date2);

$month2 += 1;   #Month is returned as 0 - 11. Make 1 - 12
$year2 += 1900; #Year is given as years since 1900. Add 1900 back to it. 

printf qq(The date is %04d-%02d-%02d \n), $year2, $month2, $day2;
```

Comment: sinan. Thanks a lot for your time and the detailed explanation. Was using a older  perl version 5.8 and thought of using the existing modules in the system. Also not sure  of how time::piece works.  Will try to download the time piece module and try it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Arav - There are built in Perl functions that can handle this in a rather primitive way, and they exist in Perl 5.8. See the Addendum in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot.   It's working.   Final output date i am stored in the below way. $outDate=sprintf("%04d%02d%02d", $year2, $month2, $day2); Hope it's correct.

Comment: @Arav I added the dashes in the `printf`, so it's easier to see what's going on and how the specifications for each part of the date are done. See [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) on how the various _%_ format codes.

Comment: Thanks David. Your answer helped me. The perl version in my prod linux os is 5.8.8. I can't use time::piece and don't have a permission to install any modules. I am working on a legacy perl program.

Answer (score 8):

I advise you use module `DateTime` and one ext for format. Also you can see modules `Date::Calc` or `Date::Parse` + `POSIX` function strftime.

```
use strict;
use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $date_str = '20120704';
my $date_obj = DateTime::Format::Strptime->parse_datetime($date_str);

my $date_res = $date_obj->subtract(days => 1)->ymd;
```

Comment: This one's a lot cleaner than mine. +1 to you, sir, for expressing intent of numbers etc. TIL ->subtract; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Will this do?

```
use Date::Parse;
use POSIX;

my $s1 = "20120704";
my $t = str2time($s1) - 86400;
my $s2 = strftime "%Y%m%d", localtime $t;

print "$s2\n";
```

Watch out for `localtime` vs `gmtime`, and leap seconds if you care about those.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple `strptime`/`strftime` roundtrip. Since `strftime` normalises inputs it is simply to just subtract 1 from the mday field.

```
use POSIX 'strftime';
use POSIX::strptime 'strptime';

my $fmt = "%Y%m%d";
my @t = strptime "20120704", $fmt;
$t[3] -= 1;  # 1 day
my $str2 = strftime $fmt, @t;
```